# How to filter dropdown list values by another dropdown list in ASP.NET, c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, filter

I have a simple question about filters.
I have 4 dropdown lists which filter the data in my web application from MySQL database table.
The first dropdown list is already selected showing only one project_id but the others drop down lists displays all the possible values from the database - this is what I made so far.

But I want to display only the data values for that particular project selected.

It's ASP.NET 4.0, C# behind and MySQL database used.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out following links for populating cascading drop down list.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CascadingDropDown.aspx

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLFirst" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"
                onselectedindexchanged="DDLFirst_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Secord</td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSecond" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                onselectedindexchanged="DDLSecond_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>    
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Thrid</td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLThird" runat="server"><asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>    </asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

// Code behind
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // your code to bind the first drop downlist

```
        }
    }

    protected void DDLFirst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DDLFirst.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            string FirstDDLValue = DDLFirst.SelectedItem.Value;
            // below your code to get the second drop down list value filtered on first selection


        }

    }

    protected void DDLSecond_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DDLSecond.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            string SecondDDLValue = DDLSecond.SelectedItem.Value;
            // below your code to get the third drop down list value filtered on Second selection


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you guys it really helped. So what I need is AJAX ToolKit and CascadignDropDown control.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this. Without the AJAX Toolkit.. somehow i does not work for me and i'm getting confused.. :[

Comment: You can do it by postback. when Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged event bind second dropdownlist. and on second selectedindexchanged bind third drowdownlist.

Comment: Hello again Pragnesh. I still don't have any success for that.
Do you have some more info on how to use the postback and the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Answer (score 3):

Filter the second dropdown datasource with selectedvalue of first  dropdown control

see this article [http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-filtering-with-two-dropdownlists-](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-filtering-with-two-dropdownlists-cs)

Comment: Link's broken, and I can't edit as it's under six characters.  URL should be http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-filtering-with-two-dropdownlists-cs