# Populating one DropDownList with another in a DataList control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Have two dropdownlist inside the edit template of a DataList. The first dropdwon is for state while the second is for town. The state is populated from a table state while the second from a table town when state is selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a lot of questions. Search the site, it's been answered a lot of times (like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119165/how-to-filter-dropdown-list-values-by-another-dropdown-list-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webforms, then you can create SelectedIndexChanged event who added to second dropdownlist values.

If simpley html use javacript and ajax. When selects the first dropdownlist value, create javascript ajax event to get data and put them all in second dropdownlist.